# Simulate y86 program as per Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective 3e Student Site

Tags: simulator, y86

I would like to simulate y86 program in a simulation environment. I followed the Chapter 4 processor architecture from [this link](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/students.html). I downloaded the `sim.tar` file from source distribution. I unzipped the file using following commands on linux.

```
linux> tar xf sim.tar
linux> cd sim
linux> make clean
linux> make
```

I got `misc`, `pipe`, `ptest`, `seq`, `y86-code` subfolder under sim folder.

Under seq subfolder there is a file called seq-full.hcl which I want to simulate on simulation environment.

I got some instruction from `README` file under `Chapter 4: Processor Architecture Y86-64 tools and documentation -> README` tab. Here is the link [README](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/README.sim). I also got some instruction simulator guide [link](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/simguide.pdf) from the same tab.

But I did not understand how could I run the `seq-full.hcl` after reading so many study materials.

If you read simguide [study material](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/simguide.pdf) you can find different section there. The 1st section is installing. I went through the commands as I mentioned early but this gave me a sim folder and sub folder under sim folder.

The section `3.3 - Simulator Command Line Options` this is not clear to me.

If anyone has any idea how to install the simulator and run program on it please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You list a set of directories. Have you looked for any executable program files instead?

Comment: Also, the `README` you link to say that the `.hcl` files in the `seq` directory is for the SEQ abd SEQ+ simulators, which seems to be named `ssim` and `ssim+`. Are there any `ssim` or `ssim+` executable program files anywhere?

Comment: Seq folder contains Makefile, README, seq.tcl, seq*+.tcl, seq+-std.hcl, seq-full.hcl, seq-std.hcl, sim.h, ssim.c  files. Which one is executable among them?

Comment: If you click on https://github.com/myyoutubechannel/Architecture/tree/main/sim/seq you are able to see the files on seq. Please do not consider abc file. This is just my test file and not related to others.

Comment: In addition, http://www.cs.williams.edu/~jeannie/cs237/labs/lab3/index.html also helpful. In the `Building and Testing Your Solution` section and `Building a new simulator.` subsection how can I modify `$ make VERSION=full
` command if the name of my file is seq-full.hcl.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you don't know how to use a shell and the `ls` command to look for executable programs, then I suggest you take a quick shell refresh course. Also I didn't say the executable files where in the sub-directories, only that they *could* be.